# Add npm run build to Fortrabbit deploy process

Tags: npm, build, pipeline, continuous-deployment, fortrabbit

Using Fortrabbit to deploy a `PHP` app which uses a node project for the front end. Is there any way in which I can add `npm run build` to the deploy process instead of having to always build first manually and then deploying it through Fortrabbit?

(There is a `fortrabbit.yaml` file on the `fortrabbit` site that needs to be configured for every `fortrabbit` app but the [example](https://help.fortrabbit.com/deployment-file-v2) doesn't show how we can add that command in the deployment pipeline.)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. There is no way to run Node JS during deployment on fortrabbit yet.

Comment: Are there any plans for this yet?

Comment: We are working on a new stack. It will be included.

Comment: Awesome! Sorry if it's public already, but is there a roadmap or estimated date of release?

Comment: Sorry no ETA. Not in 2023. In the meanwhile consider using GitHub Actions like so: https://blog.fortrabbit.com/how-to-use-github-actions